# Was Waldo a reference to any true story?

Tags: black-mirror

My question is about *Black Mirror* Episode 3 from season 2, titled *The Waldo Moment*. Was the story of this episode in any way based on some true story? Were there ever any artificial characters that became a politician, or was it all meant to be just a reference to celebrities going into politics, like for example Arnold Schwarzenegger becoming Governor of California?

Comment: I think a donkey was elected mayor of a town in Mexico once. Is that the kind of thing you’re after?

Comment: Was there any artificial character that became politician? You need certain "existence" traits to became a politician and run in elections. So that would be no. Was is based on real life events? Yes - Donald J. Trump (I wouldn't say Boris Johnson because he might be a muppet but he is a politican not a celebrity that became politician)

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY Actually BJ started his career as a journalist (although that title gives him more credence than he deserves).

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you, that article is a satisfying answer to me.

Comment: Maybe related: Wikipedia page about non-human electoral candidates https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-human_electoral_candidates

Comment: The Waldo moment aired three years before President Trump ran for office, so it is unlikely he was an inspiration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The initial inspiration was a British band called *Gorillaz*.

According to [this interview](https://www.wired.co.uk/article/charlie-brooker) with the show's creator Charlie Brooker, the Waldo character was initially based on a virtual band called [Gorillaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorillaz). The band exists only as a cartoon, though real musicians are behind the music. Brooker states that he had an idea of some character like that actually running for office. He was fascinated by the idea that such a politician, not being a real person, would be scandal-proof. He also states that the character was inspired by British politician Boris Johnson because like Johnson, Waldo doesn't act like a politician by trying to be inoffensive and dignified all the time. Another source of inspiration was a comedian who was elected as the mayor of Reykjavik.